# SQL +AJAX + PHP POST REQUEST

Tags: php, html, ajax, mysqli

Im trying to use PHP to delete a row in a SQL database.
The row is decided by the name of the product the user types in.

I created a simple form to delete products that have already been entered:

```
<article>
    <section>

        <fieldset><legend><span>Would you like to add a Product?</span>    </legend>

        <form method="POST" id = "myForm" name="myForm" onsubmit="return     false;">

        <br> &nbsp;

        <p>Enter a name of product <input type='text' id='name' name =     'name'/></p>

        <br> &nbsp;

    <input name="submit" id ="submit" type="button" value="Find Product"/>

        </form>
        </fieldset>

        <div id="fetchProduct">
        </div>

    </section>
</article>
```

Say I have already entered the data on another form and it goes into the database, but when I try to delete it I am getting the Undefined index: name in error when i try to delete.

Here is the script im using to delete the product:

```
<?php

include("database/connect_database.php");


     $name = $_POST['name'];


 $query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE product_name = '$name' ";

 $result = $database->query($query) OR die ("Failed query $query");
echo $database->error."<p>";

if($result){

    echo "Record deleted";
}
else {

    echo "Product not found!";
}

?>
```

Im also using AJAX to pass through the name:

```
  fetch = function () {

// declare the two variables that will be used
var xhr, target, changeListener;

// find the element that should be updated
target = document.getElementById("fetchProduct");

var name = document.getElementById("name").value;

var variable = "name="+name;

// create a request object
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

changeListener = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {

        target.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    } else {
        target.innerHTML = "<p>Something went wrong.</p>";
    }
};

xhr.open("POST", "deleteProductSQL.php", true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = changeListener;
xhr.send(variable);

 };


 pageLoaded = function () {
var fetchButton = document.getElementById("submit");
if (fetchButton) {
    fetchButton.addEventListener("click", fetch);
}
 };

window.onload = pageLoaded;
```

Could anyone point out where im going horribly wrong here because I just cant identify why it isn't allowing me to delete the row and why im receiving the undefined error.

Thankyou for your time

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability. Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Answer (score 0):

Put your PHP code in isset()

```
if (isset($_POST['name']){
//code here
}
```

---

Also

```
<p>Enter a name of product <input type='text' id='name' name = 'name'/></p>
```

In this line, `<p>` is not a self-closing tag so

```
<p>Enter a name of product <input type='text' id='name' name = 'name'></p>
```

Comment: I tried that and the error message has gone, but it isn't passing anything through, the value is coming through as empty? Thank you for your help

Comment: Actually, I have learnt AJAX from jQuery, so I can't help you with your JS code. Otherwise, your PHP looks rather flawless.